# Unwanted #target_name at the url at onclick of a button

Tags: javascript, html

I have defined an pop up modal at the onclick of a button.i:e when user clicks the button,it opens up a overlay modal with div=pop1 .

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/1.html#pop1
```

However when I click the button,I see the '#pop1' also gets appear at the url box.Any Idea how to remove this .

Below is my anchor/button tag

```
<a href="#pop1">Pop-up One</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [fragment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) appears because you used a `<a>` tag with a `href` attribute and your browser thinks of it as a link to follow.

You could use another html element with a specified id, such as `<button id="pop1">`. You will then be able to target it with JS (`document.getElementById`) and map your click event.

Here is a [minimal case](http://jsfiddle.net/mfx8J/).